# DADDAD chord progression on guitar

Tags: guitar, chord-progressions, alternative-tunings

I have a chord progression:
Verse:
Dm9 D9#5 Dm9 D9#5 Dm9 A7#5 D
Chorus:
Gm9 F6/9 G D9 D7 D

When going from the last D in the chorus to the first Dm9 in the verse, it sounds incongruous. Any ideas how to bridge that?

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), then please use the "Edit" button to tell a bit more about the problem and target the question more.

Comment: (My first impulse would be: the same way you got from Dm to D at the end of the verse: via the dominant, A.)

Comment: I don't see how the alternate tuning relates to the question here. I would suggest either removing the tag or specifically discussing fingering issues with your progression, depending on which you feel is more important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two time tested ways. One is the obvious V>I, as in A(7)>D(m9). The other would be to use the tritone substitution of the A7, which would be E♭7.